# Get accurate location of the visitors in website if they have GPS in their mobile phone or tablet

Tags: api, geolocation, location

I need to get accurate location of the visitors in my **website** if they have GPS in their mobile phone or tablet... i need to get accurate latitude and longitude of the visitors using their GPS...

I have searched more but all result shows for mobile apps but i need to implement in browser based website

Is it possiable?.. have any API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [W3C HTML5 Geolocation API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). This doesn't require a mobile app and the API is supported by all major mobile browsers. You can use it to do something like this:

```
MIN_ACCEPTABLE_ACCURACY = 20; // Minimum accuracy in metres that is acceptable as an "accurate" position

if(!navigator.geolocation){
    console.warn("Geolocation not supported by the browser");
    return;
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){

    if(position.accuracy > MIN_ACCEPTABLE_ACCURACY){
        console.warn("Position is too inaccurate; accuracy="+position.accuracy");
        return;
    }else{
        // Do something with the position

        // This is the current position of your user
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }

}, function(error){
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.error("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.error("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            console.error("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            console.error("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
},{
    timeout: 30000, // Report error if no position update within 30 seconds
    maximumAge: 30000, // Use a cached position up to 30 seconds old
    enableHighAccuracy: true // Enabling high accuracy tells it to use GPS if it's available  
});
```

Comment: Works well! thank you - This should be on w3schools as an example.